# Write binary data with FileSystemObject write()

Tags: javascript, binaryfiles, filesystemobject

I am developing a function in Javascript using FileSystemObject, where I just have to write in a file the binary data we are provided. This is my function.

```
function exportFile(data)
{   
    var fso, f2;
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    f2=fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\example.js",true);
    f2.Write(data);
    f2.Close();
}
```

Nevertheless it doesn't always work (error on f2.Write(data)). I guess it is because one or both reasons:
- Write function does not accept binary data (ASCII from 0-255)
- There is a maximum size for "data" in f2.Write(data)

Could you help me, please?

UPDATE:

I get this error (translated): Message: Argument or call to function not valid
Which technology should I use, then, if Javascript doesn't work with plain block 8 bit values?

Comment: What value does `data` have when the error is thrown? What's the error?

Comment: What is the error you get?  I suspect this is going to be quite difficult from Javascript because Javascript really has no appropriate data type for holding a block of plain 8-bit values. Javascript strings are 16-bit Unicode characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileSystemObject` is notably limited, even for writing UTF-8 files satisfactorily I have had to resort to another solution: `ADODB.Stream`

http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/ado_ref_stream.asp